# How do I format Watson Discovery results to look like a Watson Assistant response?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

We are developing a chat bot using Watson Assistant and when it produces a response from Discovery, it displays it in a box that isn't a chat bubble, as seen in the attached image. It seems like there is a formatDiscovery function in App.js that might have to do with it, I'm just not sure what has to be edited and what to do in order to achieve this. Is there a way to format it so that the first result is displayed in a chat bubble and not the separated window? Thanks!!

```
formatDiscovery(resultArr) {
    resultArr.map(function(result, index) {
        const formattedResult = <DiscoveryResult key={'d' + this.state.discoveryNumber + index} title={result.title} preview={result.bodySnippet} link={result.sourceUrl} linkText={'See full manual entry'} />;
        this.addMessage({ message: formattedResult });
}.bind(this));
```

[image: Chat bot output]

Comment: What are you referring to? Any code to share? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line in the function from:

```
this.addMessage(result.bodySnippet);
```

to this

```
this.addMessage({ label: 'Discovery Result:', message: String(result.bodySnippet), date: (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()});
```

This works for me when I test on a Discovery tutorial, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, this produced the result I was looking for